# Firebase: Reference an image in the storage from database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Is there any way to make a reference from my Firebase database to a image uploaded from Firebase Storage ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Javier please elaborate your scenario, not getting your point actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store either the `gs://` URI or an `https://` download URL in the Realtime Database, and use Storage (or an HTTP library) to download it.

See the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE) and [source code](https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c) for Zero to App for one way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike, really helpful!